# Run an application with different TimeZone

Tags: linux, wine, timezone

I have an windows application (Under Wine) that only works when I change timezone to NewYork's TimeZone.
with Any other zone it doesn't start!!
So, Is it possible in Linux to run an application with different TimeZone than system configured TimeZone?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, set the `TZ` environment variable:

```
TZ=America/New_York myapplication
```

I don't know if Wine has its own configuration in addition to or overriding the environment variable.

Comment: Does not work for thunderbird. :(

Comment: @panzi It does for me on Ubuntu 14.04 (Thunderbird 38.8.0).

Comment: It doesn't for me in Thunderbird 45.1.1 on Fedora 23, but I found a config option in Thunderbird. Need to restart Thunderbird before it's applied to the calendar, which is what I actually wanted to do (show a calendar in a different timezone).